# Changing element individual style background-color with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, background-color

Element I want to change

```
<button id="thumb" onfocus="focus()" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; background-color: white; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: -3px; left: 50%; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888888;">
</button>
```

Function called:

```
function focus() {
    document.getElementById('thumb').style.background-color="blue";
}
```

The error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

I don't understand why this is an error. I think it might be because of the `-` symbol. It works with other styling e.g. `document.getElementById('thumb').style.width="10px"` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With dash-ed styles you need to use **camelCase**.
So with

```
-lowerCase = Uppercase
```

For Example

```
background-color : backgroundColor;
font-size : fontSize


 function focus() {
     document.getElementById('thumb').style.backgroundColor="blue";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('thumb').style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way instead of using JavaScript is to use CSS to change the colour of the button on focus.

I have provided an example below I hope it helps.

**CSS**

```
.item-input:focus {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

**CSS CLASS:** Ensure to include class="item-input"

```
<button id="thumb" class="item-input" onfocus="focus()" style="height: 12px; width: 12px; background-color: white; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: -3px; left: 50%; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888888;">
</button>
```